# Enabling native debugging and pressing F12 key raises __debugbreak

Tags: c#, debugging, unmanaged, opentk

In an application using [OpenTK](https://github.com/opentk/opentk), enabling native debugging and pressing F12, the debugger breaks:

> A breakpoint instruction (__debugbreak() statement or a similar call) was executed in ...

The call stack isn't of much help to spot the cause:

```
ntdll.dll!DbgBreakPoint()
ntdll.dll!DbgUiRemoteBreakin()
kernel32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk()
ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart()
```

I first thought this was [related to AeDebug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18997754/how-to-disable-f12-to-debug-application-in-visual-studio-2012), however it isn't:

- changing [Auto](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-2000-server/cc939483(v=technet.10)) does nothing
- changing [UserDebuggerHotKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-2000-server/cc939487(v=technet.10)) does nothing
- changing [Debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-2000-server/cc939486(v=technet.10)) does nothing
- rebooting computer, resetting Visual Studio options does nothing

Simplest application [where it happens](https://github.com/aybe/DebugBreakF12):

```
using OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL;
using OpenTK.Mathematics;
using OpenTK.Windowing.Common;
using OpenTK.Windowing.Desktop;
using OpenTK.Windowing.GraphicsLibraryFramework;

using var window = new MyGameWindow(GameWindowSettings.Default, NativeWindowSettings.Default);
window.Run();

public class MyGameWindow : GameWindow {
    public MyGameWindow(GameWindowSettings gameWindowSettings, NativeWindowSettings nativeWindowSettings)
        : base(gameWindowSettings, nativeWindowSettings) { }

    private double TotalTime { get; set; }

    protected override void OnUpdateFrame(FrameEventArgs args) {
        TotalTime += args.Time;
        
        if (KeyboardState[Keys.F12])
            TotalTime = 0;
    }

    protected override void OnRenderFrame(FrameEventArgs args) {
        GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit);
        GL.ClearColor(Color4.FromHsv(new Vector4((float)TotalTime % 10f / 10f, 1.0f, 0.5f, 1.0f)));
        SwapBuffers();
    }

    protected override void OnResize(ResizeEventArgs e) {
        base.OnResize(e);
        GL.Viewport(0, 0, e.Width, e.Height);
    }
}
```

launchSettings.json:

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "DebugBreakF12": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "nativeDebugging": true
    }
  }
}
```

**Question:**

How can one disable the `__debugbreak` behavior when F12 key is pressed?

Or should I simply forget using F12 key when native debugging is enabled?

Comment: @HansPassant I have seen that answer, I posted it in my question actually. What are you suggesting that I may have overlooked?

Comment: I'll randomly guess this is a 32-bit process, so you need to edit HKLM/Software/Wow6432Node/.../AeDebug

Comment: It's a 64-bit process unfortunately, I tried grepping both GLFW and OpenTK to see if they may contain `__debugbreak` but nothing. Very puzzling...

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks to your suggestion I made some progress, when setting platform target to x86 instead, the bug vanishes, so that's related to 64-bit. Now I'm getting `StackOverflowException` in `SwapBuffers` after letting it run for a few minutes but I guess that's for another question.